# Making a larger sum

Tags: math-mode

I have the following code, and the sum sign isn't tall enough, the fraction sticks out from the top and bottom, how do I correct this?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$$\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k!}$$
\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try using `\[ \displaystyle\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k!} \]`.

Comment: Don't use `$$...$$` for equations. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503

Comment: That's how the summation sign is expected to be. Don't worry.

Comment: @Levy Isn't `\[ \]` already display style?

Comment: @Teepeemm yes it is! You code compiled properly here. I thought it could be of some help using that to archive what you needed.

Comment: the normal setting is what you show, summation is a stylised sigma and isn't normally stretched to be the same height as the summands.

Answer (score 6):

You may try with the `relsize` package:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{relsize}

\begin{document}

\[ \sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k!} \]
\[ \mathlarger{\sum}_{k=n+1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k!} \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Various packages let you draw larger-than-normal `\sum` (and `\prod` and `\int` and ...) symbols. Here are the choices offered by the `mtpro2` math font package. The red one is produced by `\sum` in display-style math mode. (Aside: The full `mtpro2` package is not free of charge; however, it's `lite` subset -- which is all that's needed to create the following screenshot -- is indeed free. It can be downloaded from [this site](https://www.pctex.com/mtpro2.html).

[image]

That said, it would be extremely unusual, to put it mildly, to ever require anything larger than `\xl\sum`. Speaking for myself, the symbols drawn by `\XL\sum`, `\XXL\sum`, and `\XXXL\sum` are beyond any conceivable (but still legitimate) typographic need.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
\begin{document}
$\vcenter{\hbox{$\Sigma$}}           % just for reference
 \sum                                % appearance in text-style (inline) math mode
 \displaystyle \textcolor{red}{\sum} % appearance in display-style math mode
 \xl\sum 
 \XL\sum \XXL\sum \XXXL\sum$
\end{document}
```