# Multiple lines in math mode with the same sum sign

Tags: math-mode

So I was trying to improve the readability of my paper and was wondering if there is any way to make the following look slightly more appealing. [image]

Is it possible to have the sum sign with substack bigger and span over multiple math lines, some thing like
[image]

For reference, the code I have is

```
\begin{equation}\label{e.main_bound_Q2}
\begin{split}
\mathbb{II}_1:=\sum_{\substack{|\alpha'|+|\alpha''|\leq|\alpha|\\|\beta'|+|\beta''|\leq|\beta|\\|\sigma'|+|\sigma''|\leq|\sigma|\\|\alpha'|+|\beta'|+|\sigma'|\leq 6}}&\mathds{1}_{\gamma+2s\in \left(0,\frac{1}{2}\right)}\int_0^{T}(1+t)^{1+\delta}\norm{(1+t)^{-\frac{1+\delta}{2}}\jap{x-(t+1)v}^2\jap{v}\derv{''}{''}{''} g}_{L^2_xL^2_v}\\
&\times \norm{\derv{'}{'}{'} g}_{L^\infty_xH^{\frac{1}{2}-\delta}_v}\norm{(1+t)^{-\frac{1+\delta}{2}}\jap{x-(t+1)v}^2\jap{v}\der g}_{L^2_xL^2_v}\d t\\
\quad+\sum_{\substack{|\alpha'|+|\alpha''|\leq|\alpha|\\|\beta'|+|\beta''|\leq|\beta|\\|\sigma'|+|\sigma''|\leq|\sigma|\\|\alpha'|+|\beta'|+|\sigma'|\geq 7}}&\mathds{1}_{\gamma+2s\in \left(0,\frac{1}{2}\right)}\int_0^{T}(1+t)^{1+2\delta}\norm{(1+t)^{-\frac{1+2\delta}{2}}\jap{x-(t+1)v}^2\jap{v}\derv{''}{''}{''} g}_{L^\infty_xL^{\infty}_v}\\
&\qquad\times \norm{\derv{'}{'}{'} g}_{L^2_xL^1_v}^{\frac{2(\gamma+2s-2)}{3}+2}\norm{\derv{'}{'}{'} g}_{L^2_xL^2_v}^{-\frac{2(\gamma+2s-2)}{3}-1}\\
&\qquad\times \norm{(1+t)^{-\frac{1+2\delta}{2}}\jap{x-(t+1)v}^2\jap{v}\der g}_{L^2_xL^2_v}\d t,
\end{split}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: You might consider adding something vaguely along the lines of "We denote the system of inequalities [your first three inequalities] by [some brief X]", and then substituting that in for a less awkward substack..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with @Fintan's comment that it is a good idea to define a variable to denote the inequalities. But if you want to use a substack, one option is to simply `\smash` the sum: (I didn't bother with defining all the missing macros to create a MWE):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools, amsfonts, dsfont}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\norm{\lvert}{\rvert}
\let\jap\relax
\let\derv\relax
\let\der\relax


\begin{document}
\begin{equation} \begin{split}
    \label{e.main_bound_Q2}
    \mathbb{II}_1 \coloneqq 
      \smash{\sum_
        {\substack{|\alpha'|+|\alpha''|\leq|\alpha| \\
                   |\beta'|+|\beta''|\leq|\beta|\\|\sigma'|+|\sigma''|\leq|\sigma|\\
                   |\alpha'|+|\beta'|+|\sigma'|\leq 6}}}
      &\mathds{1}_{\gamma+2s\in \left(0,\frac{1}{2}\right)}
      \int_0^{T}(1+t)^{1+\delta}
      \norm{(1+t)^{-\frac{1+\delta}{2}}
      \jap{x-(t+1)v}^2\jap{v}
      \derv{''}{''}{''} g}_{L^2_xL^2_v}
    \\
    &\quad\times 
      \norm{\derv{'}{'}{'} g}_{L^\infty_xH^{\frac{1}{2}-\delta}_v}
      \norm{(1+t)^{-\frac{1+\delta}{2}}
      \jap{x-(t+1)v}^2
      \jap{v}\der g}_{L^2_xL^2_v}\d t
    \\[10pt]
    \quad+
    \smash{\sum_
        {\substack{|\alpha'|+|\alpha''|\leq|\alpha|\\
                   |\beta'|+|\beta''|\leq|\beta|\\|\sigma'|+|\sigma''|\leq|\sigma|\\
                   |\alpha'|+|\beta'|+|\sigma'|\geq 7}}}
    &\mathds{1}_{\gamma+2s\in \left(0,\frac{1}{2}\right)}
     \int_0^{T}(1+t)^{1+2\delta}
     \norm{(1+t)^{-\frac{1+2\delta}{2}}
     \jap{x-(t+1)v}^2\jap{v}
     \derv{''}{''}{''} g}_{L^\infty_xL^{\infty}_v}
    \\
    &\quad\times 
     \norm{\derv{'}{'}{'} g}_{L^2_xL^1_v}^{\frac{2(\gamma+2s-2)}{3}+2}
     \norm{\derv{'}{'}{'} g}_{L^2_xL^2_v}^{-\frac{2(\gamma+2s-2)}{3}-1}
    \\
    &\quad\times
      \norm{(1+t)^{-\frac{1+2\delta}{2}}
      \jap{x-(t+1)v}^2
      \jap{v}\der g}_{L^2_xL^2_v}\d t,
  \end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

which gives

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is quite nice. The issue with defining the inequalities with a new variable is that I have 14 terms like this haha

Answer (score 1):

A poor implementation of `\xmathlarger[<larger size>]{<equation>}`, based on `\larger` from `relsize` package.

The name of command `\xmathlarger` follows `\mathlarger` from `relsize` package, see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/472909/79060) for a use example for `\mathlarger`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{relsize}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\xmathlarger[2][1]{%
  \mbox{\larger[#1]$\displaystyle#2\m@th$}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Normal size
\[
  \sum a + b
\]

Enlarged size
\[
  \mathop{\xmathlarger[3]{\sum}}_{\substack{i = 1 \\ j = 1}}
  \begin{aligned}
    a &+ b \\
      &+ c + d
  \end{aligned}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

You might use nested `aligned`. I'd exclude enlarging the summation sign.

I supplied mock definitions for `\derv` and `\der`. About `\d`, I'd not encourage using `\renewcommand` on it; when your bibliography will contain some author where `\d` (underdot accent) is needed, you'll be in *big* trouble.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools,amssymb,dsfont}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\jap}{\langle}{\rangle}

\newcommand{\derv}[3]{DERV}%????
\newcommand{\der}[1]{#1}%   ????
\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{e.main_bound_Q2}
\begin{split}
\mathbb{II}_1:=
\sum_{\substack{
  |\alpha'|+|\alpha''|\leq|\alpha|\\
  |\beta'|+|\beta''|\leq|\beta|\\
  |\sigma'|+|\sigma''|\leq|\sigma|\\
  |\alpha'|+|\beta'|+|\sigma'|\leq 6
}}&
\begin{aligned}[t]
 &\mathds{1}_{\gamma+2s\in \left(0,\frac{1}{2}\right)}
  \int_0^{T}(1+t)^{1+\delta}\norm{(1+t)^{-\frac{1+\delta}{2}}\jap{x-(t+1)v}^2\jap{v}
  \derv{''}{''}{''} g}_{L^2_xL^2_v}\\
 &\qquad\times \norm{\derv{'}{'}{'} g}_{L^\infty_xH^{\frac{1}{2}-\delta}_v}
         \norm{(1+t)^{-\frac{1+\delta}{2}}\jap{x-(t+1)v}^2\jap{v}\der g}_{L^2_xL^2_v}\diff t
\end{aligned}
\\[2ex]
+\sum_{\substack{
  |\alpha'|+|\alpha''|\leq|\alpha|\\
  |\beta'|+|\beta''|\leq|\beta|\\
  |\sigma'|+|\sigma''|\leq|\sigma|\\
  |\alpha'|+|\beta'|+|\sigma'|\geq 7
}}&
\begin{aligned}[t]
 &\mathds{1}_{\gamma+2s\in \left(0,\frac{1}{2}\right)}
  \int_0^{T}(1+t)^{1+2\delta}\norm{(1+t)^{-\frac{1+2\delta}{2}}\jap{x-(t+1)v}^2
  \jap{v}\derv{''}{''}{''} g}_{L^\infty_xL^{\infty}_v}\\
 &\qquad\times \norm{\derv{'}{'}{'} g}_{L^2_xL^1_v}^{\frac{2(\gamma+2s-2)}{3}+2}
  \norm{\derv{'}{'}{'} g}_{L^2_xL^2_v}^{-\frac{2(\gamma+2s-2)}{3}-1}\\
 &\qquad\times \norm{(1+t)^{-\frac{1+2\delta}{2}}\jap{x-(t+1)v}^2\jap{v}\der g}_{L^2_xL^2_v}\diff t,
\end{aligned}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the tip!